# Inconsistencies when running vue dev mode vs production

Tags: django, vue.js, django-templates

I am working on a django project where we use Vue js in some of our templates. When  I run Vue in production everything works as excepted. When I switch over to the development version of Vue I encounter all sorts of errors, not warnings but actual errors. It appears that all the errors seem to be with importing functions/objects from other files. For instance, we have a vuex store declared in another file which can not be found in the main instance of Vue when running in development but works fine in production. The same happens with functions located in a utils file. What really confuses me is that this all used to work in development at some point. I have collected static, I have cleared browser cache, have set debug to True, and doubled checked the imports. Has anyone else had this problem or have any ideas on how to go about fixing it?

### Edit

[image]

Comment: Can you share the error as well?

Comment: Sure added a screenshot above

Comment: Do you also get an error during build time? Any thing in the terminal?

Comment: No there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

As per Official Vue [Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html#Turn-on-Production-Mode).

> During development, Vue provides a lot of warnings to help you with common errors and pitfalls. However, these warning strings become useless in production and bloat your app’s payload size. In addition, some of these warning checks have small runtime costs that can be avoided in production mode.

In short, Vue doesn't throw the errors in Production as it is truncated in production build for Vue.

You need to resolve those errors while development in order to work everything properly.

Hope this help!

Comment: I am aware of this but everything works correctly in production. This all used to work correctly in development as well. All of this worked, I then submitted a pulled request and switched branches. I checked out the branch again to make changes for the pull request and now it is throwing errors. All of that happened within the span of a couple of hours so I am pretty sure nothing major as changed in the code/enviroment. If I switch back to the minfied version everything works fine again. It doesn't make sense. Why could it find the store before but not now.

Comment: Please add the code of the branch that is throwing an error. Currently looking the error screenshot, I can understand that those errors are only for Development mode. While in Production Vue build, those errors are not included.

Comment: I was able to narrow it down to this line `v-if="store.getters.getAssignmentFailed"` in the main template. It loads the template fine its not until I click a button to trigger a drawer that it complains. Is it bad practice to use store in the templates, this would probably be better suited for a computed property?

Comment: Yes, this would be better used inside a computed property.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is stuck on this and Googling around looking for ideas, I had this happen to me as well; I was using a newer JS feature (optional chaining) that worked fine in dev, but then in the production build it broke part of the app. I edited the code to remove optional chaining, and then it worked again.